# Captcha Code not validating/ working client side in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

**My issue is while i am validating Captcha code on Client Side then it stores one last value or null value initially in hidden value and in captcha image it showing one step ahead.In view of that i am not able to Captcha code on client side .  Here is code that i have used**

> **This is My Captcha Control Code**

`

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    ' Generate the CAPTCHA text
    Dim captchaText As String = GenerateRandomText()

    ' Store the CAPTCHA text in the session
    context.Session("HiddenCaptchaText") = captchaText

    ' Prevent caching of the CAPTCHA image
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()

    ' Generate and display the CAPTCHA image
    GenerateCaptchaImage(context, captchaText)
End Sub


Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub GenerateCaptchaImage(context As HttpContext, captchaText As String)
    Dim width As Integer = 200
    Dim height As Integer = 60

    Using bitmap As New Bitmap(width, height)
        Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
            ' Create a drawing font and brush
            Dim font As New Font("Arial", 28, FontStyle.Bold)
            Dim brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

            ' Draw the background
            graphics.Clear(Color.LightGray)

            ' Draw the text with distortion
            For i As Integer = 0 To captchaText.Length - 1
                Dim x As Single = i * (width / captchaText.Length)
                Dim y As Single = height / 4

                graphics.TranslateTransform(x, y)
                graphics.RotateTransform(CSng((Rnd() - 0.5) * 60))
                graphics.DrawString(captchaText(i).ToString(), font, brush, 0, 0)
                graphics.ResetTransform()
            Next

            ' Draw noise (lines and dots)
            Dim rand As New Random()
            For i As Integer = 0 To 25
                Dim x1 As Integer = rand.Next(width)
                Dim y1 As Integer = rand.Next(height)
                Dim x2 As Integer = rand.Next(width)
                Dim y2 As Integer = rand.Next(height)
                graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, x1, y1, x2, y2)

                Dim dotX As Integer = rand.Next(width)
                Dim dotY As Integer = rand.Next(height)
                graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, dotX, dotY, 2, 2)
            Next

            ' Set the content type for the response
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/PNG"

            ' Save the image to the output stream
            bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GenerateRandomText() As String
    ' Generate a random alphanumeric string for the CAPTCHA
    Dim random As New Random()
    Dim chars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Dim captchaText As New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6).Select(Function(s) s(random.Next(s.Length))).ToArray())
    Return captchaText
End Function
```

'
**this is my default page code**

```
Private Sub Default2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Retrieve the CAPTCHA text from the session
        Dim captchaText As String = Session("HiddenCaptchaText")
        ' Set the value of the hidden field
        HiddenCaptchaText.Value = captchaText
    End If
End Sub
```

**This is My Default aspx script for client side validation page**

```
     <div>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCaptchaText" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
          <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCaptcha" runat="server" title="Enter Captcha" CssClass="txtBox" AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter Captcha" Height="20px" ViewStateMode="Disabled" />                                 
                                <img src="Captcha_Control.ashx" style="width: 130px; height: 30px" alt="CAPTCHA" id="imgCaptcha" />
         <asp:Button ID="BtnEnter" runat="server" Text="Login" TabIndex="0" OnClientClick="return validateCaptcha();"/>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

> 

```
 function validateCaptcha() {
     var userEnteredText = document.getElementById('<%=TxtCaptcha.ClientID %>').value;     
     var captchaText = document.getElementById('HiddenCaptchaText').value; // Get CAPTCHA text from the hidden field
     console.log('Hid  '  +captchaText);
     if (captchaText !== null && captchaText.length > 0) {
         console.log("Expected Captcha: " + captchaText);

         if (userEnteredText.length === 0) {
             alert('Please enter the CAPTCHA text.');
             return false;
         }
         if (userEnteredText !== captchaText) {
             alert('Captcha Incorrect!');
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     } else {
         // Handle the case when captchaText is not available
         alert('CAPTCHA not available. Please refresh the page.');
         return false;
     }
 }
```